# I am getting data from firebase Realtime Db and fetching on recyclerview issue is Collection.shuffling is repeating same item in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

Here is my code. Also, I am using auto-clicking on index 0, How do I Stop Repeating items when shuffling?

```
     if (ref != null) {
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        list = new ArrayList<>();
                        String state;
                        String UserEmail;
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Deal value = ds.getValue(Deal.class);
                            value.setKey(ds.getKey());
                            state = "" + ds.child("VideoStatus").getValue();
                            if (state.equals("incomplete"))
                                list.add(value);
                            Collections.shuffle(list);

                        }
                        AdapterClassssautoclicker adapterClassssautoclicker = new AdapterClassssautoclicker(list);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterClassssautoclicker);

//                        recyclerView.swapAdapter(adapterClassssautoclicker);

                    }


                    int pos = 0;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos) != null)
                                Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(pos)).itemView.performClick();
                        }
                    }, 1);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });

        }


    }
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Code is repeating Items I want to remove repetition  while shuffling

Answer (score 0):

According to your last comment:

> Code is repeating Items I want to remove repetition while shuffling

To solve this issue, you have to get the following line of code:

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Out of the for loop as you see in the following line of code:

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    Deal value = ds.getValue(Deal.class);
    value.setKey(ds.getKey());
    state = "" + ds.child("VideoStatus").getValue();
    if (state.equals("incomplete"))
        list.add(value);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
```

In this way, you are shuffling the elements only once, and not at every iteration. In this way you can avoid duplicate elements.